# Query by global secondary index from AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query a DynamoDB table by a global secondary index from the AWS console.  The web UI gives me an option to "query" and "scan".  If I try the "query" tab, it requires the primary partition key.  If I try the "scan" tab, it proceeds to use up a lot of read capacity (and takes a long time).

How do I use the AWS Console to do a query by a global secondary index?

Answer (score 2):

I found it.  In the query tab, the "table or index" can be changed to the global secondary index.  I didn't notice that it was a drop down.

Comment: You also could have used PartiQL for DynamoDB in the console and do SELECT * FROM "tablename"."indexname" WHERE attribute = 12345